# Django: query with ManyToManyField count?

Tags: python, django

In Django, how do I construct a COUNT query for a ManyToManyField?

My models are as follows, and I want to get all the people whose name starts with A and who are the lord or overlord of at least one Place, and order the results by name.

```
class Manor(models.Model):
    lord = models.ManyToManyField(Person, null=True, related_name="lord")
    overlord = models.ManyToManyField(Person, null=True, related_name="overlord")
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So my query should look something like this... but how do I construct the third line?

```
people = Person.objects.filter(
       Q(name__istartswith='a'), 
       Q(lord.count > 0) | Q(overlord.count > 0) # pseudocode
).order_by('name'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's not the count you're interested in here, but just whether or not there are any members in that relationship.

```
Q(lord__isnull=False) | Q(overlord__isnull=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, better resort to [raw SQL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

```
for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE...'):
    print p
```